# Tragen Autos die Logos oder Embleme ihrer Hersteller?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

Der Mercedes-Stern, die Audi-Ringe, der Opel-Blitz – sind das nun Logos oder Embleme? In der Automobilpresse finden sich beide (und weitere) Bezeichnungen. Was ist der korrekte *Oberbegriff* für die Hersteller-Symbole auf den Kühlern oder Kofferräumen der Fahrzeuge?

Es geht hier nicht um das Zeichen an sich, wie es auch auf einem Briefkopf oder in der Werbung abgedruckt sein kann, sondern um das Bauteil am Auto. Wenn ich in meiner Jugend einen Mercedes-Stern abgebrochen habe oder Mike D von den Beastie Boys ein VW-"Medaillon" umhängen hatte, was habe ich da abgebrochen und was hängt dem Rapper um den Hals? Kein Markenzeichen, sondern ... ?

Comment: "... sind das nun Logos oder Embleme?" - Ja.

Answer (score 2):

Für mich ist *Emblem* etwas Dreidimensionales, also zum Anfassen. [Meyers Konversationslexikon von 1895](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=105001) definiert es gar als

> bei den Alten Name von Werken der bildenden Kunst und zwar der Toreutik

Der Begriff scheint da aber schon im Aufweichen begriffen zu sein, weil es weiter heißt

> daher ist Emblem auch s. v. w. Zierat überhaupt; ferner Sinnbild, Symbol

Bei einem Logo kann ich den materiellen Aspekt nicht erkennen, sogar der Inhalt einer Embedded Postscript Datei kann mit Fug und Recht als Logo bezeichnet und als Bildmarke geschützt werden, siehe auch in Wikipedia [Wort-Bild-Marke](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wort-Bild-Marke), wo netterweise im ersten Absatz gleich alle genannten Begriffe vorkommen.

Fazit: Keine scharfe Trennung der Begriffe erkennbar.

Comment: Definiert Meyer auch, wer _die Alten_ sind? Interessanter Fund auf alle Fälle :)

Comment: @Marzipanherz "Die Alten" war im 17. und 18. Jhdt. eine gebräuchliche Bezeichnung für die Schriftsteller und Philosophen der römisch-griechischen Antike.

Comment: @OpelBlitz Wieder was gelernt, danke!

Answer (score 1):

Da Du konkret nach dem Bauteil fragst, bietet sich der Begriff *Kühlerfigur* an.

Hier mal aus dem entsprechenden [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BChlerfigur):

> Die Kühlerfigur ist Zierde und Erkennungsmerkmal vieler Automobilhersteller. Sie war ursprünglich auf dem Kühlerdeckel angebracht; sie befindet sich durch die veränderte Bauart heute auf der Motorhaube. Berühmte Kühlerfiguren sind der Mercedes-Stern und die „Spirit of Ecstasy“ von Rolls-Royce.

Bei Automarken ohne eigene Kühlerfigur (Audi-Ringe, Opel-Blitz) halte ich die Begriffe *Logo* und *Emblem* für austauschbar.
Siehe zum Beispiel Bedeutung 1c in folgendem [Duden-Eintrag](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/emblem)

> **Emblem**
>   Substantiv, Neutrum - a. Sinnbild; Symbol, Wahrzeichen; b. Kennzeichen eines Staates, Hoheitszeichen; c. Zeichen, Logo

Answer (score 1):

Einen Mercedesstern, ein springender Jaguar oder die Emily auf einem Rolls (also dreidimensionale Objekte) sind wohl weder Logos noch Embleme, sondern *Kühlerfiguren*.

Bei einem VW oder BMW ist es eher eine *Plakette* als ein Emblem oder Logo (das ist das, was darauf abgebildet ist).

> Eine **Plakette** ist ein allgemein eher kleines Schild aus Metall oder Kunststoff mit beliebiger Form. ... Die **Plakette** ist einseitig mit einer reliefartigen Darstellung, teilweise auch mit einer Beschriftung versehen. Plaketten werden meistens auf einem anderen Gegenstand aufgebracht, z. B. an ein Bauteil oder auf einen Stein, aber auch auf Bekleidung.

Comment: Kann nicht ein Jaguar oder Mercedesstern sowohl Logo, als auch Emblem wie auch eine Kühlerfigur sein?

Comment: @userunknown So, wie die Frage gestellt ist, nicht.

Comment: @userunknown Ein Mercedesstern kann meiner Ansicht nach tatsächlich alles drei sein. Aber damit ist er wohl eine große Ausnahme.